# Obstruction to embedding a point-line graph in $R^2$

Tags: co.combinatorics, discrete-geometry

Assume you have a set X (of points) and subsets $A_i$ with the following conditions:

(1): For any two points in X exactly one of the sets contain them. 
(2): Any two subsets intersect at most at one point.

The question is: 
Can we find $|X|$ points in the plane such that the $A_i$ are exactly the lines through them.

Possible combinatorial obstructions are Sylvester's theorem, Desarges and Papus Theorem as indicated below. What other obstructions are there? Can these graphs  be characterized?

Comment: It sounds like a problem that could be hard for the existential theory of reals (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals), in which case there might be no easy characterization (by a finite number of obstructions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the number of *ordinary lines* is [actually much bigger than one.](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dirac-motzkin-conjecture/) So if you have a design with few subsets of size $2,$ it cannot be realized.

Answer (score 1):

Of course no. For example, Pappus and Desargues theorems are obstructions.

Comment: It is not immediate that the three conditions the OP states do not imply Pappus/Desargues (I am not saying that this is surprising, merely that it is not immediarte).

Comment: I've edited the question accordingly.